# Reference request for reviews on dark matter

Tags: resource-recommendations, dark-matter

Could anyone suggest some good reviews on dark matter? I'm looking for something recent. I'm interested in both theory and numerical approaches.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/5613/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic I am asking for recent reviews, you linked me to a question from 10 years ago. I do not see how that makes any sense.

Comment: General tip: Editing a question automatically propels it to the review queues.